# Не работают кнопки discord.py

Tags: python, discord, button

У меня есть шаблонный код, который я добавил в своего бота:

```
from discord_components import DiscordComponents, Button, ButtonStyle, InteractionType
import discord
from discord.ext import commands 

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")
bot.remove_command("help")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
 print("Module loaded!")
 DiscordComponents(bot, change_discord_methods=True)

@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
 embed = discord.Embed(title = 'Testing')
 await ctx.send(embed=embed, components = [Button(style = ButtonStyle.green, label = 'Button 1', custom_id="butt1"), 
                                           Button(style = ButtonStyle.red, label = 'Button 2', custom_id="butt2")])
 interaction = await bot.wait_for("button_click", check = lambda i: i.custom_id == "butt1")
 await interaction.send(content = "Button 1 clicked!")
 interaction = await bot.wait_for("button_click", check = lambda i: i.custom_id == "butt2")
 await interaction.send(content = "Button 2 clicked!")

bot.run("TOKEN")
```

Проблема в том, что при нажатии на одну из кнопок Discord пишет "Ошибка взаимодействия", но в консоли никакой ошибки не выходит.
Пожалуйста, помогите исправить.

Answer (score 1):

Смотри. в interaction(который я делаю обычно responce обычно делается проверка на клин и на автора клика.
Что бы кнопка выводить сообщение по нажатию кнопки измени код на:

```
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
 await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(title='test'),
components = [
    Button(style = ButtonStyle.gray, label ='Button1', custom_id="1"),
    Button(style = ButtonStyle.gray, label ='Button2', custom_id="2")
    ])
 responce = await bot.wait_for('button_click', check=lambda message: message.author == inter.author)
    if responce.component.id == '1': #вроде так, id не пользуюсь
       await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(title='1'))
```

На примере моего кода думаю ты сможешь разобраться со своей ошибкой(если кнчн она актуальна)